# Windows Service execute logic after OnStart

Tags: windows, service, timer, jobs

I have a Windows Service which has several timer jobs in it.  In the OnStart method, I am starting all those timers.  In effect, it takes a lot of time starting the service from the Services console and most of the time, it reports this:
Windows could not start the '*servicename*' service on Local Computer.
The service did not repond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

I know I could create a timer which encapsulatesthe other timers so I could start them outside the OnStart event.  However, I'm looking for other possible solutions as I don't like the idea of having a separate timer which does nothing other than start the other processes.

Comment: Why does it take so long to start the timers?  Are there hundreds of them?  Are you sure you are returning from OnStart?  (Failure to do so is the usual cause of that error message.)

Comment: No, there are less than 20.  Our custom timer classes performs web service and database calls when they start.

Comment: I know it is returning from OnStart because I'm not encountering the error before.  When I added 2 more timers, that's when I got the error.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't generally safe to perform external operations such as web or database calls during OnStart, because you can't predict how long they will take, and [an excessively long service startup time can interfere with the system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685138(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The Service Control Manager (SCM) waits until the service reports a status of SERVICE_RUNNING. It is recommended that the service reports this status as quickly as possible, as other components in the system that require interaction with SCM will be blocked during this time. Some functions may require interaction with the SCM either directly or indirectly.

So the proper solution is to move this initialization into a separate thread.

However, if you don't want to do this, you can call [RequestAdditionalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The RequestAdditionalTime method is intended to be called by the overridden OnContinue, OnPause, OnStart, or OnStop methods to request additional time for a pending operation, to prevent the Service Control Manager (SCM) from marking the service as not responding.

Comment: Well, this is right but it doesn't actually explain how to "execute logic after OnStart" as asked. The clarification I need is: can I run some code once the service reports a status of "SERVICE_RUNNING"?

Comment: @Flash, the service doesn't report SERVICE_RUNNING until you return from OnStart.  So you have to start a separate thread to do the service's actual work.